# Files missing from Dock

Tags: dash-to-dock

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 with the Ubuntu Dash to Dock extension.  For some reason the Files icon is no longer in the dock, and I can't figure out how to restore it.  I know there's a simple thing I'm missing, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried pinning it to the dock just like how you add any other app's icon to the dock?

Comment: I was going to, but I can't seem to find the app.  Is there a way to find it I'm overlooking?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the same?? You can use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506404/edit) and add it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem!  Somehow Nautilus had gotten uninstalled.  I reinstalled it and everything's good now.